# JavaScript dynamically defining properties

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JS framework and came across something odd (or I'm missing completely obvious)

I define properties on objects using `Object.defineProperty`. However using this within a for loop will result in some funky values. Somehow the last property added will always be the assigned value. For example if I'd assign something to attribute `one` it gets assigned to attribute `three`. Here's an example (and here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5xLdC/)

```
var Test = function(){};
var props = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
for(var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
  Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, props[i], {
    get: function() {
      return this['_'+props[i]];
    },
    set: function(val) {
      this['_'+props[i]] = val;
    }
  });
}
var test = new Test();
test.one = 'one';
console.log(test.three) // => 'one'
```

If I'd wrap this up in a `forEach` loop it works perfectly fine. What I'm guess at is that they all hold the same `get`/`set` functions due to scope errors (on my part?).

Could anyone explain as to why this happens?

EDIT:

Also possible to solve with a [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
get:(function(y) {
   return function() { return this['_'+props[y]]; }
})(i)
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787643/object-defineproperty-get-set-closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` and `set` are functions that all *reference* the same variable, `i`.  By the time you call the function outside the loop, `i` is 3.  When you use `forEach`, the function defining the properties gets the index or key as a parameter, which is a different entity in each call.

Comment: Ah yes, but of course! See, I knew I missed something completely obvious ;-) Thanks a lot! (Accept in 7 minutes)

Comment: @JeffreyW. Almost everybody does this once.  `array.forEach` ftw.